# Tip of my tongue: Word that means cultural identifier

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm trying to remember a word that means a **trait that identifies which side of a cultural divide someone falls on**. The word would be used like this:

"They knew I was American when I pronounced 'herb' without the h sound. 'Herb' is a _____ between British and American English."

The word would often be used more locally, as something that someone says that starkly identifies them as belonging to a particular region or culture that otherwise might not be apparent--like saying crawfish vs crawdad, for example.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The word you are looking for is likely **shibboleth**, as explained by [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shibboleth):

> In modern English, a shibboleth can have a sociological meaning, referring to any in-group word or phrase that can distinguish members from outsiders – even when not used by a hostile other group. It is also sometimes used in a broader sense to mean jargon, the proper use of which identifies speakers as members of a particular group or subculture.

Here’s a similar example:

> During World War II, some United States soldiers in the Pacific theater used the word *lollapalooza* as a shibboleth to challenge unidentified persons, on the premise that Japanese people often pronounce the letter L as R or confuse Rs with Ls.

Comment: That's exactly the right word — but note that it might not be very widely understood.  Also, that you wouldn't talk of “a shibboleth _between_” two cultures; you'd probably say e.g. “a shibboleth _that distinguishes_ between” two cultures.

Comment: See Judges 12:6 in the Bible.
https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=judges+12&version=ESV