# What is the word for a particular distinguishing feature that lets you identify someone or something?

Tags: single-word-requests

There's a word which I've heard before but can't remember, and haven't been able to find by searching Thesauruses. I think it sounds either Germanic or Greek. It means the particular distinguishing characteristic that lets you identify something.

E.g. I might be talking about English accents, and say that in the North of England some people say "bus" with the [ʊ] vowel, whereas in the South people use the [ʌ] vowel. So the [ʊ] is a ______ of the Northern accent.

Can anyone help me find this word?

Comment: A couple options are [tell](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/tell) and [giveaway](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/giveaway).

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shibboleth ?

Comment: indicator, hallmark?

Comment: Also: [token](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/token#English) or [sign](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/sign).

Comment: I'm pretty sure shibboleth was the word I was looking for :). Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Tip of my tongue: Word that means cultural identifier](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/542576/tip-of-my-tongue-word-that-means-cultural-identifier) I've flagged it as a duplicate, both because it seems very close, and because since this question has been answered in the comments it may not get a proper answer.

Answer (score 0):

A **diagnostic** is a distinguishing mark, feature etc; it is more often used attributively than as the standalone noun. It is often, but not solely, used in medical contexts. From [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/diagnostic#:%7E:text=1a%20%3A%20of%2C%20relating%20to,noun):

> **diagnostic** [adjective] ...
>
> [diagnostic tests] 2: serving to distinguish or identify
>
> - a diagnostic feature .....................
>
> **diagnostic** [noun]  ...  2: a distinguishing mark

An example of a non-medical (but attributive) use from [GeoScience World; 2018](https://pubs.geoscienceworld.org/gsa/geology/article-abstract/46/10/891/548169/FRIGN-zircon-The-only-terrestrial-mineral?redirectedFrom=fulltext):

> - In addition to the localities described here, examples of what can now
>   be classified as FRIGN zircon have been documented at Meteor Crater
>   (Barringer crater, USA), at the Acraman impact structure (Australia),
>   and in Australasian tektites. Occurrences thus span five continents,
>   range in age from Precambrian (ca. 590 Ma) to recent (ca. 49 ka), and
>   serve as a diagnostic indicator of impact metamorphism that may be
>   present throughout much of the geological record.

And a use of the standalone noun, from [an article on linguistics by Minjeong Son](https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.962.3610&rep=rep1&type=pdf):

> - *Thus, telicity cannot be used as a diagnostic for syntactic constituency.*

A less formal alternative is **marker** [[M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/marker)]:

> **marker** [noun]  ...
>
> 5: something that serves to identify, predict, or characterize: such
> as *genetic marker*

An example from [ResearchGate](https://www.researchgate.net/figure/EDXRF-spectra-obtained-before-and-after-patina-removal_fig3_273399234):

> - .. *fluorescence spectra obtained from patina and cleaned region are shown in Fig. 3. The main changes that can be observed are in the peak
>   relative width and in the intensity of the background, which is a
>   marker for the presence of a patina layer.*